# Can a minor attend a Genius Bar appointment alone?

Tags: repair, apple-store

Can someone under 18 attend a Genius Bar appointment alone, if the device is in their name and they know the Apple ID details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you need to be over 18. They might accept a minor with ID but it is not guaranteed:

> 1.7 No Sale to Minors. Purchase under these terms is available only to those who have reached the age of majority.

([Source](https://www.apple.com/uk/legal/sales-support/terms/repair/generalservice/servicetermsen/))

Also confirmed by a recent live chat.